# Как собрать воедино ряд из нескольких симоволов

Tags: python

как можно в принте (без импортов библиотек) красиво объединить значения, а так же добавить в конце знак "i". Вид должен быть примерно такой Х1_2 = 1,99+/-2,03I.

```
p = 1,99
l = 2,03
x1_2 = str([p] + [l] + 'i')

print('x1_2 =', x1_2, '+/-', l, "I")
```

Когда пишу у меня выходит 1,99 +/- 2.03 I

Answer (score 2):

```
p = 1.99
l = 2.03
print(f'X1_2 = {p}+/-{l}I')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p = '1,99'
l = '2,03'
print('X1_2 =', p + '+/-' + l + "I")
```